# Symfony 4 - UniqueEntity : I want that several companies may use the same name for a service but a company can't have two services with the same name

Tags: symfony, constraints, entity, unique

in my symfony project I have a groupValidators entity that is used to create a service within a company by indicating the name of the service and users...

**GroupeValidateurs.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GroupeValidateursRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 *  @UniqueEntity(
 *  fields = {"nom"},
 *  message = "Ce nom a déjà été utilisé"
 * )
 */
class GroupeValidateurs
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Nom du service
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * Liste des utilisateurs membres du service
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="groupe")
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Validateur", mappedBy="groupeValidateurs", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"ordre" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $validateurs;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Entreprise", inversedBy="services")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $entreprise;
```

And I want a company to be unable to enter the same service name twice (hence my @UniqueEntity), but I still want more than one company to use the same name for a service. For example company A can have a service called "Commerce", and company B too.
How could I do that? Because currently, if a company tries to create a service with a name already used for the service of another company, I have my constraint which intervenes

Comment: You should not use plural in your Classname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the id of the company and the name of the service in this entity, you can use unique constraint on two columns in your table definition:

```
/**
 *
 * @Table(name="GroupeValidateurs", 
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @UniqueConstraint(name="service_entreprise", 
 *            columns={"service", "entreprise"})
 *    }
 * )
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take care when you use french in your class name. People might think here you are speaking about Validator, which is not the case. I suggest you to rename your class `GroupeValidateurs` to something more speaking like `Division` or `Department` or `Service`. Also when you use a class name use singular.

What you need to do is add a constraint to ensure you don't have many times the same service name. You did that part correctly with your annotation.

Then you want :

- One company has one service
- One service can be related to many companies

So your problem is here

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Entreprise", inversedBy="services")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $entreprise;
```

You need to use `OneToMany` here as one service can be related to many companies

EDIT: I might have missread your question I didn't saw you seems to want a company can have not one service but two services. For this part we need you to provide your Company class.

Comment: I have several companies that can each have several services. A service belongs only to one company but a company can have several services. As for your comment on the name I use, yes you're right, I planned to make the changes :)